# DotFiles for Chrome Dev Tools: How Can I Load Customisations into Chrome Dev Tools Console?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I've ended up with a bunch of snippets (keyboard shortcuts that expand into text strings - see AutoHotKey on Windows and Raycast on MacOS) which have come from repetitive strings i enter into Chrome Dev Tools (CDT).

Is there a concept of something like a shell's "dotfile", for CDT console, which allows me to initialise each console with some functions i use frequently?

I suspect there must be because CDT injects an "$" and "$$" object for me every time i open it. It doesn't appear to be exposed in the CDT menus, maybe it's injectable via some attribute of a table in one of the sqlite files in my profile or something like that?

**Illustrative Example**

1. I'm browsing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fastest_production_motorcycles_by_acceleration and i want to extract the fastest accelerating bikes introduced in the 2010's (2010-2019).
2. I press F12 to open CDT, i press CMD+Shift+C (MacOS) to enter element selection mode, i click on the first cell and i can see that my data is in an HTML table
3. I press Escape to open the console drawer in CDT
4. I type into the console `,qsa` which is a keyboard macro defined in my AutoHotKey (when i'm on Windows) or Raycast (when i'm on MacOS) - this causes `[...document.querySelectorAll("|")]` to be inserted to the console and my caret / cursor is located at the point marked by `|`
5. I  type `.wikitable:first-of-type tr` then i move to the end of the line and type `,,mit` which appends `.map(e => e.innerText)` to the whole expression and i can see in the live feedback below the entry box that i'll need to slice off the first row
6. I edit the input to look like: `[...document.querySelectorAll(".wikitable:first-of-type tr")].slice(1).map(e => e.innerText)`
7. At this point i might do some more processing, e.g. `.replace(/\[\d+\]/, "")` (i typed `,,rit` to enter the `.replace(/|/, "")` placing the cursor at `|`) that superscript text in the time column and `.split(/\t/)` split the tabs to give me rows of columns (an array of arrays) and of course `.filter(r => r.startsWith("201")` filter down the rows to those i care about
8. I'm free to `console.table()` this (by typing `,,ct`) or more likely `fetch("...my private service...", { method: "POST", ... }` (this needs a couple of shortcuts composed together) post it to a file in a tempdir in my home directory.

**Summary**

My current setup works, i use this approach for all sorts of applications but i can't help wonder if there's a better way of persisting this kind of thing (and little helper functions) in my CDT - i could then share with co-workers etc.